# How to run a lua file in cmd from Sublime Text 3?

Tags: lua, terminal, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to run lua files in cmd (for a reason I can't use build system).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to call a cmd command you can easily write your own plugin.
 
Just open your user directory and create a python file (e.g. `run_lua.py`).
Or just go with Tools >> New Plugin. 
This plugin runs the command `lua $file` and afterwards pauses until the user pressed a key:

```py
import subprocess
import sublime_plugin

class RunLuaCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        view = self.window.active_view()
        subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "lua", view.file_name(), "&", "pause"])
```

Add the key binding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["alt+b"],
    "command": "run_lua",
},
```

For a more general approach:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class RunCmdCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, command):
        variables = self.window.extract_variables()
        command_expanded = sublime.expand_variables(command, variables)
        # run in cmd
        command_arr = ["cmd", "/c"]
        # run the command
        command_arr.extend(shlex.split(command_expanded, posix=False))
        # afterwards wait for a key
        command_arr.extend(["&", "pause"])
        # execute the command
        subprocess.Popen(command_arr)
```

With the key binding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["alt+b"],
    "command": "run_cmd",
    "args": {
        "command": "lua $file"
    }
},
```

PS. You can also use `cmd /k` instead of `cmd /c` and omit the `& pause` at the end to create a cmd, which will stay open after executing the command. With pause it will wait for a keypress and close.
Thanks to @EgorSkriptunoff for the hint.

Comment: One can use `cmd /k ...` instead of `cmd /c ... & pause`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff with `cmd /k` there will be a open cmd after the execution. With `& pause` it will close with a keypress, which is a better behavior in my opinion.

Comment: With `cmd /k` it is possible to enter arbitrary console commands after your script terminated, which is quite useful.  Press Alt+Space, C to close console window (3 keys instead of 1).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks I personally prefer the way in the solution. However I agree, that it is worth to mention one could also use `cmd /k` instead. Hence I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the features of the plugin I don't think you are able to do that:

> Opens a terminal in the folder containing the currently edited file
>   Opens a terminal in the project folder containing the currently edited
>   file

The plugin will only open the terminal to your project/file directory.

I think the parameters that the documentation highlights is about configuring your terminal and not to run any kind of commands.

The plugin makes your life easier anyway. You are able to open your command prompt/terminal in your working directory and then just run your command you need. After that you can use the command prompt's history (<kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> or <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>)to navigate to your previous commands.

Comment: is there a plugin to allow me do that?
I was googling for it but found just the terminal.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no such plugin, I was trying to find one in the past but I couldn't find something that satisfied my needs. But I found easy enough to just use the plugin you said, to open the current directory and just run the command I need. Is maybe a small process in the first time, but then in the second time you can use the history of your command prompt to recall the command.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the sublimeREPL plugin.  It opens a command prompt as a new "code tab".  I needed to add my lua install to my path.  It opens an interactive shell and supports a variety of shells including Lua.

Comment: I thought I'd comment versus deleting my answer:  For some Lua versions this works nicely.  But, there is a bug which for some Lua versions suppresses stdout.  For many this would be an obvious reason *not* to use the sublimeREPL plugin.