# Can't use require key word in Lua with a plugin

Tags: cmd, lua, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using plugin(the second one) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813778/how-to-run-a-lua-file-in-cmd-from-sublime-text-3) question.

When I run a code which includes "require" key word I getting this error:

```
    lua: ...:\backup\Code\Lua\FakeMagic\Master\testingarea\1.lua:3: module 'test' no
t found:
        no field package.preload['test']
        no file '.\test.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\test.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\test\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\test.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\test\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\test.luac'
        no file '.\test.dll'
        no file '.\test51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\test.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\test51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\test.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\test51.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...:\backup\Code\Lua\FakeMagic\Master\testingarea\1.lua:3: in main chunk

        [C]: ?
```

The code:

```
require "test"
test()
```

test file:

```
function test()
    print('test')
end
```

But if I try to run a code which not includes "require" with plugin all is ok.

Sometimes it's work sometimes not... but it works really rare and I coouldn't find why.

PS correct my enlish pls.

Comment: You can't @-ping someone unless they're part of the discussion thread.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas but they are made the plugin, so probably the problem specific enough to only them could solve it. That's why.

Comment: Just copy your test file to the location pointed to by error message `C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\test.lua`

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff, that works, but this is a crutch, I can't to it all the time cuz there is whole tree where one file requires another etc...

Comment: @Parki - Where do you want to store your modules?

Comment: @Parki this seems to be a lua issue since the plugin just calls lua. I don't use Lua and hence cannot help that much. In general you should inform yourself about adding files to the lua package path or including files from an other folder. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868847/lua-require-function-on-a-full-path-name) or at [require and LUA_PATH](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html).

Comment: @ r-stein it perfectly works when I runing files without using the plugin so it doesn't looks like it something with Lua.